# WP Rest API: Get User by Email

Tags: rest-api

Im looking to get user information by email address using the latest version of the wordpress restapi.
I have registered the user email field and it returns on both the "/wp-json/wp/v2/users/" and the "/wp-json/wp/v2/users/" calls but im looking for a way to basically get user by email.  I cant seem to find a way to filter or search by email field though, any thoughts?

Comment: if the core endpoints don't help you, you can create a new one : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Maybe you take a look here (_found by using google_) [wp-api sample](https://github.com/dest81/wp-api-get-user-by-username/blob/master/plugin.php#L120) and grab the code (_and correct deprecated stuff_) you need?!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the search [argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#arguments)

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?search=myemail@domain.com
```

Comment: The search argument does not search emails, it just searches the fields that are returned (name, description, slug, and a few others).

Comment: The ?search=myemail@domain.com does not work

Answer (score 0):

A tad late to the party, but the trick is to make sure your search query is url-escaped (i.e. "%40" instead of "@").

The following fetch call worked on my site:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?search=myemail%40domain.com
```

Or for a more friendly input experience (that doesn't require escaping special characters) I created this function:

```
function get_user_by_email(email) {
    return fetch( `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?${new URLSearchParams({ search: email })}` )
        .then(response => response.json());
}

get_user_by_email("myemail@domain.com")
    .then(console.log);
```